# How to access a C++ function which takes pointers as input argument from a C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PatternSequencer
{
    class Version
    {
        public string majorVersion;
        public string minorVersion;

        ushort* pmajorVersion;
        ushort* pminorVersion;
        ulong status;

        [DllImport(@"c:\DOcuments\Myapp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SRX_DllVersion")]
        public static extern ulong SRX_DllVersion(ushort* pmajorVersion, ushort* pminorVersion);


        public Version()
        {
            status = SRX_DllVersion(&pmajorVersion, &pminorVersion);
            if (status)
            {
                majorVersion = "1 - " + *pmajorVersion;
                minorVersion = "1 - " + *pminorVersion;
            }
            else
            {
                majorVersion = "0 - " + *pmajorVersion;
                minorVersion = "0 - " + *pminorVersion;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It throws an Error Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context. How do I pass pointers to the C++ dll?    I am new to C#, please help me

Comment: Declare the parameters as `ref`, which will eliminate the need for `unsafe` code.

Comment: @William: can you please explain in detail. I am new to C#

Comment: What you want to do here is known as [Marshaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx).  It's a big topic, but for simple cases like this, it's not too hard.

Comment: So I say [DllImport(@"c:\FreeStyleBuild\BERTScope\Release\Bin\BitAlyzerDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SRX_DllVersion")]
        public static extern ulong SRX_DllVersion(ref ushort* pmajorVersion, ref ushort* pminorVersion); But still it has some errors.

Comment: @user2495173 I put the example in an answer, it should work for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than using an `unsafe` context try:

```
[DllImport(@"c:\FreeStyleBuild\BERTScope\Release\Bin\BitAlyzerDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SRX_DllVersion")]
public static extern ulong SRX_DllVersion(out ushort pmajorVersion, out ushort pminorVersion);
```

To make the call:

```
ushort major, minor;
SRX_DllVersion(out major, out minor);
```

I'm assuming the SRX_DllVersion parameters are output only, if not change `out` to `ref`.

Avoid `unsafe` code when ever possible.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go; there is no reason at all to use unsafe code here.

Comment: Perfect it works!! Thanks a lot :) Where can I read more about this?

Comment: [Marshaling Data with Platform Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae.aspx) and [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) if you need samples or common imports.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you've to mark the class `unsafe` to make it work.

```
unsafe class Version
{
    [DllImport(@"c:\FreeStyleBuild\BERTScope\Release\Bin\BitAlyzerDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SRX_DllVersion")]
     public static extern ulong SRX_DllVersion(ushort* pmajorVersion, ushort* pminorVersion);
}
```

If you have only one method you could mark the method as `unsafe`.

And don't forget to turn on "allow unsafe code" compiler option as well.

Answer (score 1):

You must mark that method as `unsafe`

```
[DllImport(@"c:\FreeStyleBuild\BERTScope\Release\Bin\BitAlyzerDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SRX_DllVersion")]
public static extern ulong SRX_DllVersion(out ushort pmajorVersion, out ushort pminorVersion);
```

Comment: @user2495173 please edit your question to include the full code if you find it relevant.

Comment: That syntax can be used for a block which is part of the body of a method (or constructor, accessor). An entire class member is not inside a block.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're absolutely correct. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `unsafe` block.
More about [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).